# [visual-code]; VSCode using 100% CPU when used suddenly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm facing exactly this problem since yesterday sunday, suddenly the cpu usage went up to 100%. I'm using version 1.79.2, when I don't type anything from VSCode the CPU is idle again. I'm here wondering what might be happening, and still the problem persists! :(
Below image showing high usage of VSCode.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uURDU.png)

I researched about the problem I found, even here I came across a report of this problem with some tips that supposedly would work, however, they did not.
The link [VS Code uses 100% CPU even if it is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516186/vs-code-uses-100-cpu-even-if-it-is-closed)

Comment: Does this happen with all extensions disabled?

Comment: what do you see in the process explorer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76593213/11107541

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I will now to see when, HolyBlackCat

Comment: I disabled all extensions, and I noticed that the high CPU usage has dropped slightly, but it's still high. It's between 15% to 55% and frankly it's high.

Comment: I saw the Process Explorer and realized that the workspace I use is consuming the CPU and could it be that my workspace has a problem?